# Jest Angular test login exception

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

How can I specifically test a login exception.

```
submit() {
    const { username, password } = this.loginForm.value;
    this.store.dispatch(new Login({ username, password }))
        .subscribe(
            () => {
            },
            catchError(() => throwError(new Error(ToastCode.LOGIN_FAILED)))
        );
}
```

So far my test works but the code coverage tells me to test the error handling aswell.

So far my test:

```
it('should submit the login form', () => {
    const data = {
        username: 'test@test.de',
        password: 'test123'
    } as Credentials;
    component.loginForm.patchValue({ ...data });
    component.submitLoginForm();
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        new Login({ ...data })
    );
});
```

But I do not know how to add a test which checks the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `expect(submit()).toThrow(TypeError);` for that.

Comment: expect(submit()).toThrow('Your Message'')

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a spy on *store.dispatch*, if you do you can do

```
mySpy.and.throwError('error ...')
```

And then you can use

```
expect(submit()).toThrow(TypeError);
```

after calling *submit()* in your test

Comment: submit() would be     component.submitLoginForm(); right?

Comment: if we refer to your post submit() would be component.submit();

Comment: But how would I check it against my error message throwError(new Error(ToastCode.LOGIN_FAILED))) ?

Comment: the spy.and.throwError(...) is used to trigger the catchError of your observable and thus cover this part. I guess what you need is expect(component.submit()).toThrow(new Error(ToastCode.LOGIN_FAILED)) or something along those lines

Comment: It does not throw the error this way. My component.submit() returns void, so the expected value is different.